# Convert REST curl command to Apex Request

Tags: rest, curl, apex

I have a curl example of a REST API call as follows

```
curl https://api.endpoint.com/api_action.json \
-u key:secret \
-d 'message=Hello World' \
-d id=12345
```

Now I'm trying to replicate this using the Apex HttpRequest class but I'm unsure as to how I should be passing the options into the call.

What I have so far is as follows

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(https://api.endpoint.com/api_action.json);
req.setMethod('POST');
// what goes in these
req.setHeader(stuff);
req.setBody(stuff);

Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
```

Answer (score 1):

From @sfdcfox [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67867/novice-question-making-a-curl-callout-from-apex-to-a-3rd-party-app)

Given this comment:

curl -i -X POST --data "first_name=test&last_name=testlast&email=test@test.com&phone=1234567&company=Ac‌​meInc&years_in_business=3&amount=4000&dealer_id=524b2833f7494317db000001" https://example.com/webform/start/

The code you need would be approximately:

```
String payload='first_name=test&last_name=testlast&email=test@test.com&phone=1234567&company=Ac‌​meInc&years_in_business=3&amount=4000&dealer_id=524b2833f7494317db000001';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint('https://example.com/webform/start/');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueOf(payload.length()));
req.setBody(payload);
Http binding = new Http();
HttpResponse res = binding.send(req);
```

Comment: Just wanted to say this worked great for me in a similar use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using APEX, you can use the build-in apex_web_service.make_rest_request to do this:

```
declare
  v_clob clob;
begin
  v_clob := apex_web_service.make_rest_request( 
                        p_url            => <your URL>,
                        p_http_method    => 'POST',
                        p_body           => <whatever body>,
                        p_username       => 'username',
                        p_password       => 'password' );
  htp.p(v_clob);
end;
```